# readline: inputrc vi keys, ipython and the del key

Tags: bash, input-methods

I have the following `.inputrc`:

```
set editing-mode vi
set keymap vi-command

set show-all-if-ambiguous on
set completion-ignore-case on
```

In bash when I type following (in insert mode!) as an example,

```
# cat ~/.vimrc
```

and then press the `Home/Pos1` key and then the `Del` key the result is the following:

```
# at ~/.vimrc
```

So far so expected. Now, for `ipython`. I type:

```
In [1]: from bla import blub
```

and then press the `Home/Pos1` key and then the `Del` key the result is

```
In [1]: From bla import blub
```

the cursor is at the position of the `r` and it is not in insert mode anymore which is not what vim would do, right (not even in `compatible mode`)?

Any ideas?

I understand my workflow is not exactly vim-style but I am just very used to it sshing to non-vi keys environments.

Migrated from [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34764730/inputrc-vi-keys-ipython-and-the-del-key)

Comment: ...and upvoted. ;-) Good luck, and welcome to vi.SE.

Comment: That is a readline/ipython problem and has nothing to do with vim. Is ipython actually using readline() library?

Comment: _Given a properly built Python, the basic interactive IPython shell will work with no external dependencies. However, some Python distributions (particularly on Windows and OS X), don’t come with a working readline module. The IPython shell will work without readline, but will lack many features that users depend on, such as tab completion and command line editing._ [source](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/install/install.html) Tab completion works so ... Yes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about vi or Vim. It is, in fact, on-topic on Stack Overflow, and asking it there was the correct thing to do.